# How to determine S3 bucket URL? What does determine FQDN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am looking at my S3 buckets and I am confused how FQDN should look like.
First case

```
https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/CityData.csv
```

Second case

```
https://elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-123456789000.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/2019202gUL-eb-node-express-sample-v1.1.zip
```

I found in one tutorial that where website hosting is concerned, the bucket name is part of the
FQDN; where direct bucket access is concerned, the bucket name comes after the FQDN.
Anyway I checked my bucket and `Static website hosting` is disabled.

How is URL created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bucket url  for website have the following form:

```
https://bucket-name.s3.Region.amazonaws.com/key name
```

or

```
https://s3.Region.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/key name
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html#virtual-host-style-url-ex

Answer (score 4):

Both can be valid, that depends on the policy.

If you are serving files directly from a public bucket, the first case would do:

`https://s3.<REGION>.amazonaws.com/<BUCKET_NAME>/<FILE_KEY>`

But, sometimes you want to serve files from a private bucket. In this case, you service will deal internally, downloading the file and then serving (like the second case), or creating a presigned download url (recommended). See more about presigned urls [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/s3-example-presigned-urls.html)